# Fade in/out effect inside the 2D collider doesn't work - Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a fade in/out effect when an enemy enters or exits a 2D Collider (The enemy should remain invisible at all time when outside the collider)
The idea was initially to create the code for the Fade effect in another class, in order to make the code of the "Attack Class" cleaner, but it seems more correct to insert the Fade code inside the IEnumerator. The code works incorrectly: the character appear and disappear in the collider as if it were simply deactivated or activated, without any fade effect.
The script is attached to the enemy:

```
public class AttackManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Awake()
    {
        sprite = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
        find = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Ghost");
    }

    void Start()
    {
        tmpColor = sprite.color = new Color (1,1,1,0);
    }

    public PlayerScriptableObjects accessPlayer;
    public GhostsScriptable accessGhost;
    Color tmpColor;
    SpriteRenderer sprite;
    bool attacking;
    GameObject find;
    int durationFade = 3;
    bool enterCollision = false;
    
    IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        enterCollision = true;
        
        if(enterCollision == true)
        {
            tmpColor = sprite.color = new Color(1f,1,1f,0f);

            while(tmpColor.a < 1f)
            {
                tmpColor.a += Time.deltaTime / durationFade;
                sprite.color = tmpColor;
                
                if (tmpColor.a >= 1f)
                    tmpColor.a = 1.0f;

                yield return null;
            }

            sprite.color = tmpColor;
        }

        if (col.gameObject.tag == "CandleRadius") 
        {
            if(accessPlayer.MentalSanity > 0 
            && enterCollision == true)
            {
                Attack(7);
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D stay)
    {
        if (stay.gameObject.tag == "CandleRadius") 
        {
            enterCollision = true;

            if(accessPlayer.MentalSanity > 0 
            && enterCollision == true && !attacking)
            {
                {
                    attacking = true;

                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(accessGhost.AttackTime);

                    Attack(7);
                    attacking = false;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator OnTriggerExit2D (Collider2D exit)
    {
        enterCollision = false;

        if (enterCollision  == false )
        {
            tmpColor = sprite.color = new Color(1f,1,1f,1f);

            while(tmpColor.a >= 1f)
            {
                tmpColor.a += Time.deltaTime / durationFade;
                sprite.color = tmpColor;

                if (tmpColor.a <= 1f)
                    tmpColor.a = 0.0f;

                yield return null;
            }

            sprite.color = tmpColor;
        }

        if (exit.gameObject.tag == "CandleRadius" 
        && enterCollision == false )
        {
            Debug.Log("The monster is not attacking the PLAYER Because it is outside the COLLIDER!");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the code in another class and the fade effect works, but without respecting the boolean conditions.
I hope I have been clear about what I am trying to achieve.
Thanks for your support

Comment: The code is incomplete. Post the rest of the code, please!

Comment: please also put your code through a codeformatter

Comment: Oops... sorry, I forgot three curly braces, but the code ends here. There is an attack method in this class, but it works perfectly so I avoided posting it because I don't think it is responsible for the malfunction of the fade effect.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code would really need a formatter and some proper Coding Style, but thats not for now.
I cannot really tell you why it doesnt work with your code, because I need more information, but if I understand your problem correctly or more like the result you want to achieve is, that the Ghost should fade in the closer he is.

Instead of using colliders you could just calculate it.
I would imagine something like this:

```
[SerializeField, Min(0)] private float minAlphaDistance = 3f;
[SerializeField, Min(0)] private float maxAlphaDistance = 1f;
[SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer = null;


[SerializeField] private Transform target = null;

private Color color = Color.white;

private void Awake()
{
    color = spriteRenderer.color;
}
private void Update()
{
    DistanceToAlphaCalculation(target.position);
}

private void DistanceToAlphaCalculation(Vector3 targetPosition)
{
    //You could also use a Vector2 and ignore the Z
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(targetPosition, this.transform.position);
    if (distance < minAlphaDistance)
    {
        float percentage = 1f - (distance - maxAlphaDistance) / (minAlphaDistance - maxAlphaDistance);
        color.a = percentage;
        spriteRenderer.color = color;
    }
    else if(color.a > 0)
    {
        color.a = 0f;
        spriteRenderer.color = color;
    }
}
```

I just did it on the fly, so there are much better structure for it, but I think you can get the idea of how to use it. You calculate the percentage of the distance from the point of when you want to see the maxAlpha value and the minAlpha value. Min here as when he should hit 0f. Then you can multiply that percentage with the maxPossible Alpha value. For colors 255. And you have a linear fade in fade out. You could also use Smoothstep/Lerp/Slerp for different behaviour of it or a custom graph.

I hope it helps you, at least gives you a different Idea how to approach it :D
(The code ignores btw optimization and performance. just so you know.)

Comment: Except for my mistakes, which cannot be ruled out, the code doesn't seem to work. Let me explain: there are no errors in the compiler, but the sprite cannot be seen., 
I wish I could show you the changes, but I didn't understand if it can be done in the "comments," or I can answer my question.

Comment: I do not know your setup in the scene so I am not sure what you did wrong.

You can just add this script to the Ghost and drag the SpriteRenderer into it aswell as the Target, there you drag the Player I think in your case into it.

If you cannot see stuff you should reduce the maxAlphaDistance to 0f and the minAlphaDistance you should increase. Due to using Vector3 they need to be on the same Z position.

If this doesnt work out I can help you maybe via Discord?

Comment: Really very kind, however I'll show you the few changes I made because I wasn't able to drag the objects, and I did it via code. I added the gameobject player:
GameObject player;

And these in the Awake method:

player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
target = player.transform;
spriteRenderer = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();

The "target" works because through a Debug.log I can see the player's position, I have some doubts about the functioning of the SpriteRender. However, beyond your help, I would like to have your Discord, also to discuss. Thank you.

Comment: I btw adjusted the Code above. I found a wrong variable in usage aswell as maxValue wasnt needed. (I just wrote it here from head thats why I didnt checked it before with the IDE) Now it should work